# More than one match and exclude the beginning of the string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, expression, newline

I have this type of text from a tag:

```
RP/HDQ1S/HDQ1SJFDEAK/C8HJ/2024837        20APR23/0339Z   GLS123
        DATA
    001 OS/AF1638 J 16APR 7 CDGHAJ LK1 1250 1420/LK *1A/E*
    002 OS/AF1439 Q 20APR 4 HAJCDG LK1 0600 0735/LK *1A/E*
    003 OS/AF9466 Q 20APR 4 CDGRNS LK1 1235 1340/LK *1A/E*
    004 RF-HDQRM1S 081330 DK07E856C11618 300AB28DB011CD//HDQ1SJF
        DEAK/C8HJ/20248373/LBG/1S/T/FR/EUR CR-HDQ RM 1S 08MAR133
        0Z
```

I'm trying to merge the lines like that:

```
RP/HDQ1S/HDQ1SJFDEAK/C8HJ/2024837        20APR23/0339Z   GLS123
        DATA
    000 OS/AF1638 J 16APR 7 CDGHAJ LK1 1250 1420/LK *1A/E*
    000 OS/AF1439 Q 20APR 4 HAJCDG LK1 0600 0735/LK *1A/E*
    000 OS/AF9466 Q 20APR 4 CDGRNS LK1 1235 1340/LK *1A/E*
    000 RF-HDQRM1S 081330 DK07E856C11618 300AB28DB011CD//HDQ1SJFDEAK/C8HJ/20248373/LBG/1S/T/FR/EUR CR-HDQ RM 1S 08MAR1330Z
```

With the following expression, I managed to exclude the first line, containing "RP", but I'm only getting one match and I need to get two:

```
(^(?!RP).+)((\n        )|(\n      ))
```

I'm using it in JavaScript to replace like that:

```
text.textContent = text.textContent.replace(/^(?!RP)(.+)((\n        )|(\n      ))/gm, function (match, p1) { return p1 });
```

The goal is to merge every new line with the previous one if the new line start with 6 or 8 empty spaces, and to ignore the first line that starts with RP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to run it multiple times.

```js
const regex = /(^(?!RP).+)(\n        )/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('(^(?!RP).+)(\\n        )', 'gm')

const str = `RP/HDQ1S/HDQ1SJFDEAK/C8HJ/2024837        20APR23/0339Z   GLS123
        DATA
    001 OS/AF1638 J 16APR 7 CDGHAJ LK1 1250 1420/LK *1A/E*
    002 OS/AF1439 Q 20APR 4 HAJCDG LK1 0600 0735/LK *1A/E*
    003 OS/AF9466 Q 20APR 4 CDGRNS LK1 1235 1340/LK *1A/E*
    004 RF-HDQRM1S 081330 DK07E856C11618 300AB28DB011CD//HDQ1SJF
        DEAK/C8HJ/20248373/LBG/1S/T/FR/EUR CR-HDQ RM 1S 08MAR133
        0Z
    005 RF-HDQRM1S 081330 DK07E856C11618 300AB28DB011CD//HDQ1SJF
        DEAK/C8HJ/20248373/LBG/1S/T/FR/EUR CR-HDQ RM 1S 08MAR133
        0Z
    006 RF-HDQRM1S 081330 DK07E856C11618 300AB28DB011CD//HDQ1SJF
        DEAK/C8HJ/20248373/LBG/1S/T/FR/EUR CR-HDQ RM 1S 08MAR133
        0Z
    007 RF-HDQRM1S 081330 DK07E856C11618 300AB28DB011CD//HDQ1SJF
        DEAK/C8HJ/20248373/LBG/1S/T/FR/EUR CR-HDQ RM 1S 08MAR133
        0Z
    008 OS/AF1638 J 16APR 7 CDGHAJ LK1 1250 1420/LK *1A/E*
    009 RF-HDQRM1S 081330 DK07E856C11618 300AB28DB011CD//HDQ1SJF
        DEAK/C8HJ/20248373/LBG/1S/T/FR/EUR CR-HDQ RM 1S 08MAR133
        0Z
    010 OS/AF1638 J 16APR 7 CDGHAJ LK1 1250 1420/LK *1A/E*
    011 RF-HDQRM1S 081330 DK07E856C11618 300AB28DB011CD//HDQ1SJF
        DEAK/C8HJ/20248373/LBG/1S/T/FR/EUR CR-HDQ RM 1S 08MAR133
        DATA
    012 OS/AF1638 J 16APR 7 CDGHAJ LK1 1250 1420/LK *1A/E*`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
let flag = true;
let result = str;
while(flag){
    flag=false;
    result = result.replace(regex, function(match, p1){flag=true;return p1;});
}

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If a positive lookbehind is supported in your environment, you can assert that the previous line does not start with RP and then match a newline followed by 6 or 8 spaces which are not followed by a space:

```
(?<=^(?!RP).+)\n      (?:  )?(?! )
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zOzkAh/1)

You could also check if DATA is not after the match

```
\n      (?:  )?\b(?!DATA\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZRRDJC/1)